# List the Java source files compiled by javac

Tags: java, classpath, javac

I have a series of small Java projects (classes in *.java files) that refer to the large code repository via CLASSPATH. The code repository includes a huge number of *.java files (source files) and a few *.jar files. I would like to separate any given project from its directory in order to pack it and distribute it.

Given a Java class that contains the main method as the starting point of a given project, how do you list all the files such as *.java files or *.jar files on the CLASSPATH that are used to compile the given Java class? Can javac produce a log with sufficient details during compilation? Can you use Java API alone and programmatically check the source files used for compilation?

Comment: Java classes are compiled individually, from a single .java file.  Are you asking how to find the dependencies of a class?

Comment: 'List the Java source files found on CLASSPATH and compiled by javac': easy. None. Source files are not located via the CLASSPATH.

Comment: Yes, this is about finding the dependencies of a class - in the moment of compilation for the given class and classpath.

Comment: Good point EJP. A lot of different files are found on the classpath, so we need to see which ones are in use by logging the activities of javac and checking dependencies. Would someone care to recommend a dependency checking tool?

Comment: No: during compilation, only .class files are found via the CLASSPATH. Not 'a lot of different files'.

Comment: "If the -sourcepath option is not specified, then the user class path
is also searched for source files."
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Answer (score 2):

> Can javac produce a log with sufficient details during compilation?

[`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) has the `-verbose` option which gives you which JARs are on classpath and which Java files were compiled.

```
javac -verbose <filepath>
```

Sample output (compiling Dummy.java which uses Dummy2.java and some JDK classes):

```
[parsing started RegularFileObject[Dummy.java]]
[parsing completed 10ms]
[search path for source files: .]
[search path for class files: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\resources.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\rt.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jsse.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jce.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\charsets.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfr.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\classes,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar,C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar,.]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/File.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
[checking Dummy]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/AutoCloseable.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/net/URI.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/System.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/PrintStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/FilterOutputStream.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/OutputStream.class)]]
[loading RegularFileObject[.\Dummy2.java]]
[parsing started RegularFileObject[.\Dummy2.java]]
[parsing completed 0ms]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/StringBuilder.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/CharSequence.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/io/Serializable.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Comparable.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/StringBuffer.class)]]
[wrote RegularFileObject[Dummy.class]]
[checking Dummy2]
[wrote RegularFileObject[.\Dummy2.class]]
[total 257ms]
```

Comment: Good idea, Vasan. I was wondering if we add the logging option "-Xstdout filename", could we parse the log file and find all the compile-time dependencies of a given class, all the source files used for compilation?